# Error in Django Widget tweaks 'render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value":

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error 
'render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value":

I'm trying to use Widget Tweaks for Django to render the Form. It gives the error and highlights the line `{% render_field field class ="form-control is-valid" %}` once the page loads on the browser

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}


{% block title %}

New Topic: {{board.name}} - {{board.super}}

{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{board.name}}</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New Topic<li>
{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

   <form method="post" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

       {% for field in form %}

           <div class = "form-group" >

               {{field.label_tag}}

               {% if form.is_bound %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{error}}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% render_field field class ="form-control is-valid" %}
                    {% endif %}
                   {% else %}
                    {% render_field field class ="form-control" %}
                   {% endif %}
                   {% if field.help_text %}
                     <small class="form-text text-muted" >
                        {{ field.help_text }}
                     </small>
                   {% endif %}

           </div>

       {% endfor %}
        <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>

    </form>

    {% endblock %}

This must render the form with bootstrap styles.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. There is an extra space between the 'class' keyword and the equals sign. this is what causes the issue. when i eliminate that it resolves the issue.

instead of `{% render_field field class ="form-control is-valid" %}`

i just changed it to `{% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}`